# How to dynamically convert Javascript Object Literal to String

Tags: javascript, string, object, tostring

I want to convert

```
{
  ...
  {
    name: "Product 1",
    category: "Category 1"
  },
  {
    name: "Product 2",
    category: "Category 2"
  },
  ...
}
```

to

```
'Product 1 (Category 1)\r\nProduct 2 (Category 2)\r\n ... '
```

So my final render looks like:

```
Product 1 (Category 1)
Product 2 (Category 2)
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: The object in your question is invalid. Every element in an object needs to have a key. Is the outer one supposed to be an array?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [`join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join):

```js
const data = [
  {
    name: "Product 1",
    category: "Category 1"
  },
  {
    name: "Product 2",
    category: "Category 2"
  }
];

const res = data.map(({name, category}) => `${name} (${category})`).join('\r\n');

console.log(res);
```